# nginx alias redirect with trailing slash using different host name

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have the following nginx config which is servering a few static pages. It sits behind a load balancer and is not listening on the public host name. The problem with the below is nginx sends a 301 back to add a trailing slash but it sets the location to internal.mysite.production/blog/ not www.mysite.com/blog/

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name    internal.mysite.production
    location /blog {
        root /var/www/somewhere/;
    }
}
```

Is there an option to change this?

Comment: if this is wordpress, check the wordpress config, cause it does a redirect if the url doesn't match the settings.

Comment: thanks, not wordpress though, I am using nginx just as reverse proxy, gzip etc.

Comment: well this config can't do any redirection, it's either the app it self, or the url is matching another rule in another server maybe, ur default server.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify:

```
server_name_in_redirect on;
```

in your nginx config. also see: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name_in_redirect